# Feedback on a python script to calculate loan payoff

Tags: python, finance

I'm new to Python (C++ in college), and got sick of Excel so I decided to write a very simple loan-payoff script in Python. I learned a lot and would like feedback on things I should have done better.

One of my main self-imposed constraints was coding as natively as possible. (I would like to be able to push this script to my github so others can use it.)

1.I ran into some issues parsing inputs from the user, and (lazily) chose to `except` all errors. Is there a simple way to sanitize user inputs without writing my own parser, or calling a huge library?

2.I had wanted to upload this script to Git so others can run it, preferably without having Python installed - is this possible? I looked at pushing it to a Docker, but then they would have to have docker installed... What's a good use case for me to learn? The nearest I got was a .bat file (Win10) that opens cmd.exe and runs the script.

3.Any other general feedback.

```
def loans_available():
    try:
        from loan_data import loans
    except:
        print("No loans found.")
        loansfound = False
    else:
        loansfound = True
    finally:
        if loansfound == True:
            print(f"\nThere are {len(loans)} loans available:")
            for index in range(len(loans)):
                loan_name = loans[index]['name']
                loan_amount = loans[index]['principal']
                loan_interest = loans[index]['interest']
                print(f'{index}  |  {loan_name}...........${loan_amount} @ {loan_interest}%')
            loans_available.yes = True
        else:
            loans = []
            loans_available.yes = False
        loans_available.loans = loans
        return

def add_loan():
    loans = loans_available.loans
    loan_yes_no = input("Would you like to add a loan? [Y/N]")
    options = ('y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes')
    if loan_yes_no not in options:
        menu()
    print("Ok, let's add a loan. You will need a loan name, principal (amount owed), and yearly interest rate.")
    input("Press any key to continue when ready.")
    name = input("Loan name:")
    principal = float(input("Principal ($): "))
    interest = float(input("Interest (%): "))

    print(f"\n New Loan \n |  Name: {name}\n |  Principal: ${principal}\n |  Interest: {interest}%")
    add_me = input("Is this correct? [Y/N]")
    if add_me not in options:
        name = input("Loan name:")
        principal = float(input("Principal ($): "))
        interest = float(input("Interest (%): "))
    loan_to_add = {}
    loan_to_add['name'] = name
    loan_to_add['principal'] = principal
    loan_to_add['interest'] = interest

    loans.append(loan_to_add)
    f = open('loan_data.py', 'w')
    # f.write(str(loans))
    f.write(f"loans = {str(loans)}")
    f.close()

    print("Loan added successully.")
    menu()

def make_payment():
    from decimal import Decimal
    loans_available()
    loans = loans_available.loans
    # if len(loans)<10:
    #     print("No loans to pay off!")
    #     menu()
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("Enter the number of the loan you want to pay off:"))
        except:
            print("That's not an option")
        else:
            try:
                loan = loans[selection]
            except:
                print("That's not an option")
            else:
                loan = loans[selection]
                name = loan['name']
                principal = loan['principal']
                interest = loan['interest']
                monthly_interest = interest/1200
                print(f"You have selected {name}\nPrincipal  |  ${principal}\nInterest   |  {interest}%")
                break
        break
    while True:
        try:
            payment = float(input("Enter payment amount ($):"))
        except:
            print("Error. Enter a payment amount in dollars.")
        else:
            payment = float(payment)
            break
    z=0
    while principal > payment:
        # p = principal
        # i = monthly_interest
        equation = principal*monthly_interest+principal-payment
        y = round(equation, 2)
        print(f"{z} ${y}")
        principal = y
        z=z+1
        if z >= 2400:
            break
    if z >= 2400:
        print("Don't hold your breath, buddy.")
        menu()
    print(f'With a payment of ${payment}\nPaid in {z} months')
    menu()

def exit_app():
    print("See ya.")
    exit()

def menu():
    loans_available()
    menu_options = {1:add_loan, 2:make_payment, 3: exit_app}
    if loans_available.yes==False:
        menu_options[1]()
        return
    print(f"\nWhat would you like to do?")
    for i, j in menu_options.items():
        print (f"{i}  |  {j.__name__}")
    while True:
        try:
            menu = int(input(f"Enter the number of your selection (1-{len(menu_options)}): "))
            if menu not in menu_options:
                raise Exception
        except:
            print("That's not an option.")
        else:
            break
    menu_options[menu]()
    # menu_options.get(menu)

menu()
```

Comment: Stack overflow is for small, specific questions. As such vague/general requests and multiple broad questions are outside of the scope of this site. If you are just looking for general review of your code there is always [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Try breaking your problem into individual questions and asking them separately, and with explicit examples of how you failed to solve the problem.  General advice questions are typically not responded to all that well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll revise and post a more specific question.
I'll also take a look at code review.